# Counting matches in odd-numbered columns

Tags: excel, modulo, countif

I am trying to create an Excel function that counts occurrences of a particular string in a row.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
=CountIf($B1:$ZZ1, "myText")    -- works fine
```

The problem I am facing now is that I don’t want to count every occurrence, but only those in odd-numbered columns.

Maybe something like this?

```
=CountIf($B1:$ZZ1, "myText" AND  (GetColumn % 2 = 1))    -- not working
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B1:$ZZ1="myText")*(MOD(COLUMN($B1:$ZZ1),2)=1))
```